# jQuery - Adding sums by data-attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to `sum` all calculated totals by `data-id` but the code only correctly sums the `data-id="active"` and seemingly calculates a random value for the `data-id="pending"`. The correct value is supposed to be 1550.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-id="active"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#active_total").text(sum);
    });
    item.find(".total").text(total);
  });
  $('[data-id="pending"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#pending_total").text(sum);
    });
    item.find(".total").text(total);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid
}

.total {
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Active:
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">10</div>
  <div class="cost">5</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">20</div>
  <div class="cost">30</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
Pending:
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="sold">10</div>
  <div class="cost">100</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="sold">22</div>
  <div class="cost">25</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
Active:
<div id="active_total">0</div>
Pending:
<div id="pending_total">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calculating `sum` by running a loop on `.total`. Instead of running a loop directly on `.total` you should run a loop on `.total under data-id="active/pending"`..

So for `active` your loop will be `$('[data-id="active"]').find(".total")` and for pending total, your loop will be `$('[data-id="pending"]').find(".total")`

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-id="active"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
    var sum = 0;
    $('[data-id="active"]').find(".total").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#active_total").text(sum);
    });
    item.find(".total").text(total);
  });
  $('[data-id="pending"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
    var sum = 0;
    $('[data-id="pending"]').find(".total").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#pending_total").text(sum);
    });
    item.find(".total").text(total);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid
}

.total {
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Active:
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">10</div>
  <div class="cost">5</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">20</div>
  <div class="cost">30</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
Pending:
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="sold">10</div>
  <div class="cost">100</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="sold">22</div>
  <div class="cost">25</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
Active:
<div id="active_total">0</div>
Pending:
<div id="pending_total">0</div>
```

**Solution #2**

You should not run loop on `.total`. You are already running a loop on `data-id=active` and `data-id=pending`. Calculate the total in that loop only.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var activeTotal = 0;
var pendingTotal = 0;
  $('[data-id="active"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
    activeTotal += parseInt(item.find(".total").text());
    /*var sum = 0;
     $('[data-id="active"]').find(".total").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#active_total").text(activeTotal);
    });*/
      $("#active_total").text(activeTotal);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
  });
  $('[data-id="pending"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
    pendingTotal += parseInt(item.find(".total").text());
    /*var sum = 0;
    $('[data-id="pending"]').find(".total").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#pending_total").text(sum);
    });*/
      $("#pending_total").text(pendingTotal);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid
}

.total {
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Active:
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">10</div>
  <div class="cost">5</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">20</div>
  <div class="cost">30</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
Pending:
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="sold">10</div>
  <div class="cost">100</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="sold">22</div>
  <div class="cost">25</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
Active:
<div id="active_total">0</div>
Pending:
<div id="pending_total">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-using the sold and cost and total classes. pending adds all the classes 1550 + 650 = 2200.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-id="active"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".total").text(total);
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#active_total").text(sum);
    });
    item.find(".total").text(total);
  });
  $('[data-id="pending"]').each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".soldp").text();
    var price = item.find(".costp").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".totalp").text(total);
    var sum = 0;
    $(".totalp").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(
        $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(",", "")
      );
      $("#pending_total").text(sum);
    });
    item.find(".totalp").text(total);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid
}

.total {
  font-weight: 900
}
.totalp {
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Active:
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">10</div>
  <div class="cost">5</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="active">
  <div class="sold">20</div>
  <div class="cost">30</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
Pending:
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="soldp">10</div>
  <div class="costp">100</div>
  <div class="totalp">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-id="pending">
  <div class="soldp">22</div>
  <div class="costp">25</div>
  <div class="totalp">0</div>
</div>
Active:
<div id="active_total">0</div>
Pending:
<div id="pending_total">0</div>
```